# Como filtrar dados do Combobox utilizando o Framework Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

**Contexto:**

Estou querendo carregar os modelos do **Checklist de Modelo** no combo, mas somente os que não estão na tabela do banco de dados **checklist_estrutura**. No caso, somente seria carregado o modelo Catu, pois ele não está cadastrado na tabela **checklist_estrutura**. Como solucionar este problema? 

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modelo ER:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Consulta dos dados do checklist_modelo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Consulta dos dados do checklist_estrutura** (não tem o modelo 'catu' = 8)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

   **Controlador ChecklistEstruturaController.php contém o método novo():**  responsável por carregar o combo de modelo.

```
 //Este método apresenta o formulário para cadastrar um novo checklists de estruturas
       public function novo()
       {

          // $checklistEstrutura =  ChecklistEstrutura::all();

           $checklistModelo = ChecklistModelo::all();

          $checklistEstrutura = DB::table('checklist_estrutura')
           ->join('checklist_modelo', 'checklist_modelo.id', '=', 'checklist_estrutura.modelo_id')
           ->join('checklist_itens', 'checklist_itens.id', '=', 'checklist_estrutura.itens_id')
           ->select('checklist_estrutura.modelo_id', 'checklist_modelo.modelo', 'checklist_modelo.ativo')
           ->groupBy('checklist_estrutura.estrutura_id', 'checklist_estrutura.modelo_id')
           ->distinct()
           ->get(); 



           //testando a variável $checklistModelo
         $checklistModelo = ChecklistModelo::where('id','<>', $checklistEstrutura->modelo_id);



           $checklistItem =  ChecklistItem::all();
              return view('admin.checklistEstrutura.novo',['checklistsEstruturas' => $checklistEstrutura, 'checklistsModelos' => $checklistModelo,
              'checklistsItens' => $checklistItem]);
       }
```

Tentei fazer a filtragem dessa forma

> $checklistModelo = ChecklistModelo::where('id','<>',
>   $checklistEstrutura->modelo_id);

Mas ocorreu o seguinte erro:

> Property [modelo_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: se quiser continuar dando o Get simplesmente faça o seguinte: depois que você busca o checklistmodelo verifique se o mesmo existe: `if(isset($checklistModelo[0]->modelo_id)){ 
$checklistItem =  ChecklistItem::all();
return view('admin.checklistEstrutura.novo',['checklistsEstruturas' => $checklistEstrutura, 'checklistsModelos' => $checklistModelo,
              'checklistsItens' => $checklistItem]);
 }else{
  return back()->withErrors(['Error'=>'Não foi possível realizar a busca!' ]);
}` lembrando que nesse caso você vai precisar usar um foreach no blade

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Além do que o @Weslei respondeu, como você quer ignorar uma lista de itens, você pode combinar a função [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) e [`whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses), dessa forma:

```
ChecklistModelo::whereNotIn('id', $checklistEstrutura->pluck('modelo_id'))->get();
```

Usando o `pluck`, ele irá retornar um `array` com todos os `modelo_id` encontrados, depois, a função `whereNotIn` fará um filtro ignorando os registros com os `id` que combinarem com os que estão no `array`.

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda. Eu testei o código que você informou e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

O erro modelo_id esta ocorrendo pois quando você está realizado a consultado checklistEstrutura, você esta utilizando o método get(), está função sempre retorna um array, logo, para você poder acessar uma propriedade de seu modelo, deve ser de um elemento específico e não de um array, depois de método get(), você pode utilizar o find().

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta.